# How to place checker board in the top left corner of a turtle screen regardless of computer screen size?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I have coded how to actually draw the checker board but I need it to be placed in the top left corner of the turtle screen regardless of what computer screen someone is viewing on (the top left corner of the checker board is always at the top left corner of the turtle screen regardless if the screen is 200000 pixels across or 2000 pixels). How do I do this? thank you!

```
import turtle

def draw_box(t, x, y, size, fill_color):
t.penup()  # no drawing!
t.goto(x, y)  # move the pen to a different position
t.pendown()  # resume drawing

t.fillcolor(fill_color)
t.begin_fill()  # Shape drawn after this will be filled with this color!

for i in range(a, b):
    board.forward(size)  # move forward
    board.right(90)  # turn pen right 90 degrees

t.end_fill()  # Go ahead and fill the rectangle!


def draw_chess_board():
square_color = "black"  # first chess board square is black
start_x = 1  # starting x position of the chess board
start_y = 1  # starting y position of the chess board
box_size = 50  # pixel size of each square in the chess board
for i in range(0, 8):  # 8x8 chess board
    for j in range(0, 8):
        draw_box(board, start_x + j * box_size, start_y + i * box_size, box_size, square_color)
        square_color = 'black' if square_color == 'white' else 'white'  # toggle after a column
    square_color = 'black' if square_color == 'white' else 'white'  # toggle after a row!


board = turtle.Turtle()
draw_chess_board()
turtle.done()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll show a couple of ways for doing this.  First, I'm going to provide a working version of `draw_board()` since the one posted is broken.  I will include my prefered way of importing turtle:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

def draw_box(t, x, y, size, fill_color):
    t.penup()  # no drawing!
    t.goto(x, y)  # move the pen to a different position
    t.pendown()  # resume drawing

    t.fillcolor(fill_color)
    t.begin_fill()  # Shape drawn after this will be filled with this color!

    for _ in range(4):
        t.forward(size)  # move forward
        t.right(90)  # turn pen right 90 degrees

    t.end_fill()  # Go ahead and fill the rectangle!
```

We're going to use methods `window_width()` and `window_height()` for both solutions, as well as draw the board from top to bottom instead of bottom to top.  The first solution simply moves the starting point, using the above methods, and moves in the opposite Y direction:

```
def draw_chess_board():
    square_color = 'black'  # first chess board square is black
    box_size = 50  # pixel size of each square in the chess board
    start_x = -width/2  # starting x position of the chess board
    start_y = height/2  # starting y position of the chess board

    for i in range(8):  # 8x8 chess board
        for j in range(8):
            draw_box(board, start_x + j * box_size, start_y - i * box_size, box_size, square_color)
            square_color = 'black' if square_color == 'white' else 'white'  # toggle after a column

        square_color = 'black' if square_color == 'white' else 'white'  # toggle after a row!

screen = Screen()
width, height = screen.window_width(), screen.window_height()

board = Turtle()
board.speed('fastest')  # because I have no patience

draw_chess_board()

board.hideturtle()
screen.mainloop()
```

The second approach leaves both the X starting point, and the Y direction code alone, but instead manipulates the coordinate system to achieve the same result:

```
def draw_chess_board():
    square_color = 'black'  # first chess board square is black
    box_size = 50  # pixel size of each square in the chess board
    start_x = 1  # starting x position of the chess board
    start_y = box_size  # starting y position of the chess board

    for i in range(8):  # 8x8 chess board
        for j in range(8):
            draw_box(board, start_x + j * box_size, start_y + i * box_size, box_size, square_color)
            square_color = 'black' if square_color == 'white' else 'white'  # toggle after a column

        square_color = 'black' if square_color == 'white' else 'white'  # toggle after a row!

screen = Screen()
width, height = screen.window_width(), screen.window_height()
screen.setworldcoordinates(0, height, width, 0)

board = Turtle()
board.speed('fastest')  # because I have no patience

draw_chess_board()

board.hideturtle()
screen.mainloop()
```

This manipulation of the coordinate system will affect all that you do in the program so make sure you understand it before adding further code.

[image]

Finally, how I might have written this program if I were starting from scratch (or the merits of *stamping* over *drawing*):

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

BOX_SIZE = 50  # pixel size of each square in the chess board
CURSOR_SIZE = 20
COLOR_MAP = {'red': 'black', 'black': 'red'}  # try red just for fun

def draw_chess_board():
    square.color('black') # first chess board square is black
    start = BOX_SIZE/2  # starting x and/or y position of the chess board

    for row in range(8):  # 8x8 chess board
        square.goto(start, start + row * BOX_SIZE)

        for _ in range(8):
            square.stamp()
            square.color(COLOR_MAP[square.fillcolor()])  # toggle after a column
            square.forward(BOX_SIZE)

        square.color(COLOR_MAP[square.fillcolor()])  # toggle after a row!

screen = Screen()
screen.setworldcoordinates(0, screen.window_height(), screen.window_width(), 0)

square = Turtle()
square.hideturtle()
square.penup()  # no drawing!
square.shape('square')
square.speed('fastest')  # because I have no patience
square.shapesize(BOX_SIZE / CURSOR_SIZE)

draw_chess_board()

screen.mainloop()
```